# VBA - Pop up message for save the change

Tags: excel, vbscript

i have VBA script to retrive data from oracal DB. the script used open existing file then  do some stylish in excel.the issue is there is a pop up message said " Do you want to save change  ?" how can avoid this pop up message

```
'open a new worksheet in Excel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\combbn\Desktop\Reportt\Quary_Result.xls")
Set objSheet1 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorkbook.Activate

objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Desktop\Reportt\Quary_Result3.xls"
objWorkbook.Application.Quit
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Desktop\Reportt\Quary_Result3.xls"
objWorkbook.Application.Quit
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

with

```
objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Desktop\Reportt\Quary_Result3.xls", FileFormat:=56
objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
objExcel.Quit
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Also note the use of FileFormat. These are the main file formats in Excel 2007-2013:

```
50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)
```

Comment: Dear thanks for replay the script is VBS and cannot know the below statament     objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Desktop\Reportt\Quary_Result3.xls", FileFormat:=56    i think there is issue with  fileformat:=56

Comment: I have not tested it for vbscript but the code that I gave you.. does it give you any error?